# Getting a object reference in interface that was not passed

Tags: java, interface

Currently, the below code gives compile erorr, because the listener don't know whats smsTask. I would need a instance of the smsTask in the listener. Is it possible to do this **without** passing it in the contruntor? It seems redunant if I do:

```
.createTask(smsTask,new TaskCompleteListener(smsTask){...}
```

current code:

```
public void doStuff(){      
         SmartPhoneTask smsTask=createSmsTask();
         super.getSystem().createTask(smsTask,new TaskCompleteListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTaskComplete() {
                releaseResources(smsTask);//error.

            }});

    }

    private SmartPhoneTask createSmsTask() {
        return new SmartPhoneTask();
    }
```

createTask:

```
void createTask(SmartPhoneTask task, TaskCompleteListener listener);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the variable `final` :

```
 final SmartPhoneTask smsTask=createSmsTask();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `TaskCompleteListener` is under your control you can add a `Task` parameter to the `onTaskComplete()` method:

```
public void onTaskComplete(Task task) {
  releaseResources(task);
}
```

Now the `System` has to pass the corresponding task to the listener when the `onTaskComplete()` method is called.

With this way you can also add the same `TaskListener` to multiple tasks.